# Any ideas on why this query would run so slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, sqlperformance

1. Query one--index seek

   ```
   SELECT P.Date_Send_Ins,C.* 
   FROM DATABASE1..TABLE1 P  WITH (FORCESEEK) JOIN DATABASE2..TABLE2 C   ON P.COLUMN1  = C.COLUMN1  AND P.COLUMN2 =    C.COLUMN2 
   WHERE    LEFT(C.COLUMN3 ,7) LIKE 'YYYY/MM' and LEFT(P.COLUMN3 ,2) = 'YS'
   ```
2. Query two

   ```
   SELECT P.Date_Send_Ins,C.*
   FROM DATABASE1..TABLE1 P   JOIN DATABASE2..TABLE2 C   ON P.COLUMN1  = C.COLUMN1  AND P.COLUMN2 = C.COLUMN2 
   WHERE    LEFT(C.COLUMN3 ,7) LIKE 'YYYY/MM' and LEFT(P.COLUMN3 ,2) = 'YS'
   ```
3. Query three--index seek

   ```
   SELECT P.Date_Send_Ins,C.* 
   FROM DATABASE1..TABLE1 P   JOIN DATABASE2..TABLE2 C   ON P.COLUMN1  = C.COLUMN1  AND P.COLUMN2 = C.COLUMN2 
   WHERE    LEFT(C.COLUMN3 ,7) LIKE 'YYYY/MM' and  P.Date_Send_Ins LIKE 'YS%'
   ```

Query one and three are fast in sql server but query two is too slow and results do not appear .

In another server all of them are fast ,i run `sp_updatestats`, but it's not better .

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What indexes do you have on DATABASE1..TABLE1?

Comment: Bad index was slow down the query. The problem was solved when i disabled index.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using functions on any table columns in the where clause. Almost always a performance issue. E.g don't use LEFT()

```
SELECT P.Date_Send_Ins,C.* 
FROM DATABASE1..TABLE1 P  
JOIN DATABASE2..TABLE2 C   ON P.COLUMN1  = C.COLUMN1  AND P.COLUMN2 = C.COLUMN2 
WHERE  C.COLUMN3 LIKE 'YYYY/MM%' 
and P.COLUMN3 = 'YS%'
```

Comment: i do not use this function,but another users use that, I am DBA and i have to control SQL Server performance.

Comment: ok, but let those users know how to avoid functions on data in the where clause.... that will then help you too

Comment: Yes i know ,but my problem was solved by disable index , i agree with you functions on columns prevent the use of indexes and i told it to them